# In EF Core DbContext the attach method is not working

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am using `EF Core 2.2.4`I have the following Entity

```
public partial class Person: IBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID{ get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public byte[] VersionStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Then in service method i am modifying only certain properties of Entity

```
 public async Tak Update()
 {
    var p= new Person();
    task.FirstName = "Foo";

   _dbContext.Attach<Person>(p);
   _dbContext.SaveChanges();
 }
```

If i am not mistaking, The Attach method is used when entity is not tracked and you want to change only certain properties.

However, the above code does nothing. When i run SqlProfiler i dont see any sql is executed on SaveChanges()

Do i need to explicitly tell EF that property is modified? Something like

```
_dbContext.Entry<Person>(p).Property(p => p.FirstName).IsModified = true;
```

Comment: You need to have the ID value to make any change in database using entity framework core, please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657813/how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-core/46658779#46658779

Answer (score 0):

The Attach method is used when you have a whole entity instance but it’s not being tracked. After you attach the entity, it’s tracked, and EF Core assumes that its content matches the current database state. It provide this without the cost of loading it from the database.  Attach method does this by setting the entity’s State to Unchanged.So your call

```
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

do not execute any query because there is no change to any entity.

You can use another function

```
var entity = new MyEntity();
context.Update(entity);
```