# update values in selected columns in using EF core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am new to ASP.NET core and EF Core. I need some help to get update values in selected colums in using EF core.

I need my view to provide List of students and give an option to updated FeePaid only with out giving an option to modify rest of the data.I have tried to modify "TryUpdateModelAsync" only include fee Paid as shown below but it updates rest of the fields with null value. I am working on SQL server LocalDb for now in visual studio 2019 and Code will be published in Azure.

Thanks for your help.

```
 TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
        studentToUpdate,
        "student",
        s=> s.FeePaid)
```

In SQL I can write a query to updated only selected colums with new values.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2
WHERE condition;



public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    Student = await _context.Students.FindAsync(id);

    if (Student == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
{
    var studentToUpdate = await _context.Students.FindAsync(id);

    if (studentToUpdate == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
        studentToUpdate,
        "student",
        s => s.FirstMidName, s => s.LastName, s => s.EnrollmentDate, s=> s.Confirmed, s=> s.FeePaid))
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    return Page();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658779/7964217

Comment: `TryUpdateModelAsync` uses lambda expression(s) which represent top-level properties which need to be included for the current model when trying the update. It will take only the values of those properties and update the model. You can use view model to model binding for update properties and update use EF Core .