# EF Core Saving error for two objects depending on a second equal one

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a vey long long POCO class ("FichaCliente") that I'll simplify here emphasizing the property that's an ObservableCollection:

```
{
  public int FichaCliente1 { get; set; }
  ...
  public int FichaClienteN { get; set; }

  public ObservableCollection<Reclamado> Reclamados { get; set; }

  public int FichaClienteN+2 { get; set; }
  ...
  public int FichaClienteN+M { get; set; }
```

}

The "Reclamado" class is also a relative long POCO that has another class as element, the UF class. Thus we can understand the "Reclamado" as being:

```
{
  public int Reclamado1 { get; set; }
  ...
  public int ReclamadoN { get; set; }

  public UF Uf { get; set; }

  public int ReclamadoN+2 { get; set; }
  ...
  public int ReclamadoN+M { get; set; }
```

}

Being UF class a simple POCO as follows:

```
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Apelido { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Municipio { get; set; }
}
```

The SAVE operation to the database is handled by just the "SaveFichaAsync" method that's as simple as:

```
public async void SaveFichaAsync(FichaCliente ficha)
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext(_dBService))
        {
            context.FichasClientes.Update(ficha);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return;
        }
    }
```

What's a sure thing is that "FichaCliente" can have many "Reclamado" as it's needed. And that's fine, it works!
Just to make it clear, the UF entity is the equivalent to me as what would be states in the US, thus, a given address belongs to a state (city, state...). As "Reclamados" are distinct entities, I can have one or more "Reclamados" belonging to the same UF.

That's where it fails!

If I have the same UF for two or more different "Reclamados", a error shows, as if, it was saving twice the same UF, although they're actually different, each one belonging to a different "Reclamado". It's not saving that same UF twice. It saves one for each "Reclamado"

An example of error is:

"The instance of entity type 'UF' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 26}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached."

How can I handle this?

Comment: Are you using the same object (UF) or creating new ones?

Comment: They're are different instances... Each one for a different "Reclamado", not the same!

Comment: Just looking with more attention to the code: I have a fixed number of UF each representing one state. Whenever I reference then, I obviously am using an existing one as the states are only those. But each entity UF belongs to a different entity Reclamado, so they can't be the same...

Comment: just remove line `context.FichasClientes.Update(ficha);`

Comment: So that wont' save to the database? :O

Comment: It does. Your entry is already tracked by the context. `Update` method is only useful when the entry is not tracking

Comment: What's exactly the case....

Comment: Please, @ЯрославВиталиевич when you don't have an answer don't write something wrong as it were, because people who might solve won't look!!!

Comment: Please, explain what I wrote wrong? Did you try that and your code still is not working?

Comment: Looks like your entity model needs a serious, profound refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this could be avoided if you decouple the persistence model from the actual business code, to solve that you'll have to iterate throughout all UFs before the SaveChangesAsync and execute the following per UF

`context.Entry(uf).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`

Comment: The error changed, that is, just the Id of the it... 'Reclamado' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 0}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'...

Comment: BUT, if instead I use context.Entry(uf).State = EntityState.Added, it does work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your entry is already tracked by the context. Just remove line `context.FichasClientes.Update(ficha);` and your code will work.

`Update` method is only useful when the entry is not tracking by the Context. [Read more about update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657813/how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-core)