# How to use both update and join in a single lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I want to convert my SQL query to lambda expression.Below is the SQL query.I tried but failing to get expected result

```
UPDATE
    Sales
SET
    SI.ACP= SD.ACP
FROM
    Sales SI
INNER JOIN
    SaleDesc SD
ON 
    SI.GroupID= SD.GroupID;
```

Comment: If you tried something, then show us that, and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: At least try to code it. You want to use join or include with LINQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause and for updating you can use an ORM or ADO.Net: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657813/how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-core

Comment: AFAIK out of the box EF does not support such queries. You can look for some libraries like [bulk extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#efcorebulkextensions) or [entity framework extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#entity-framework-extensions) which possibly support something like this.

Comment: It is impossible in raw EF Core. But some [extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) may help. I'd recommend [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore). See docs: [Update](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db#update), [Join](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Join-Operators.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core itself does not support bulk and native updates and everything should go through ChangTracker.

Anyway, you can use available extensions for EF Core, which can do that without raw SQL execution. For example [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (disclaimer: i’m one of the creators)

Then you can write the following LINQ query:

```cs
var queryForUpdate =
   from si in ctx.Sales
   join sd in ctx.SalesDesc on si.GroupID equals sd.GroupID
   select new { si, sd }

queryForUpdate
   .Set(u => u.si.ACP, u => u.sd.ACP)
   .Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sales must have a PK.
you have different ways to write LINQ. this is one of the approaches (i try to make it more readable for you.)

```
Sales.Dump("original");
    Sales
        .Join(
                SaleDescs,
                sales => sales.GroupID,
                desc => desc.GroupID,
                (sales, desc) => new { Sales = sales, SaleDesc = desc }
            )
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(s =>
            {
                Sales.Where(sl => sl.GroupID == s.Sales.GroupID).FirstOrDefault().ACP = s.SaleDesc.ACP;
            });
            SubmitChanges();
            
    Sales.Dump("resulted");
```

since I have no details on table structure - i made up some for this example

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
  var p = db.Sales
        .Join(db.SaleDesc,
         left => left.GroupID,
         right => right.GroupID,
        (left, right) => new { Sales = left, ACP = right.ACP });
        
  foreach (var item in p)
  {
    item.Sales.ACP = item.ACP;
    db.Sales.Attach(item.Sales);
    db.Entry(item.Sales).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

or

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    db.Sales
    .Join(db.SaleDesc,
    left => left.GroupID,
    right => right.GroupID,
    (left, right) => new { Sales = left, ACP = right.ACP }).ForEachAsync(a => a.Sales.ACP = a.ACP);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I hope you understand that if there are thousands records this will become a nightmare?

Comment: No, I did not consider it, but I think the Update () method does the same in the lower layers.

Comment: Nope, Update from my answer generates exactly the same SQL as from question and no records are loaded to the client. In you solution you load everything and then EF sends a lot of updates

Comment: When you have "var queryForUpdate = ......" that is, you have loaded the records and then performed the update operation.

Comment: Loading records, as you know initiated by ToList, ToArray, etc. Here we have just IQueryable which is not executed yet. Execution is provided via Update, which generates appropriate UPDATE SQL.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv I edited the answer. Now you see the runtime is better

Comment: Problem here that with standard EF Core functionality you cannot gain needed performance, only such solutions (which is correct). Simple operation which just updates records from other table needs at least Dapper or other extensions.