# How to select and update specific columns by Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to convert raw SQL to EF core now.
my table has many columns, such as column1 to 10, and I need to select and update specific columns. original code like this :

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE key = "someKey"

(processing data)

UPDATE table SET column2 = someValue WHERE key = "someKey"
```

first, I tried like this :

```
var query = 
  from model in context
  where key == "someKey"
  select model;

query.First().column2 = someValue;
context.SaveChanges();
```

this code works very fine as I wished, but SQL generated like this :

```
SELECT key, column1, column2, ... column10 FROM table WHERE key = "someKey"
```

I do not want select useless columns so I tried this:

```
var query = 
  from model in context
  where key == "someKey"
  select new myDTO
  {
    Item1 = model.column1,
    Item2 = model.column2
  };

query.First().Item2 = someValue;
context.SaveChanges();
```

this code generates SELECT SQL statement exactly I wished, but cannot generate update statement. (obviously, myDTO is not registered into DbContext)
How can I do this with EF Core?

Comment: Maybe you can find the answere in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657813/how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-core

Comment: @TobiasS  it seems that solutions in that post cannot be avoid select all columns.

Comment: Just my opinion, I don't think that it's possible, and didn't understand why you want to limit some columns to be returned only just for update. Based on your scenario, I would suggest using [`.FromSqlRaw()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) to update specific column. Flow: 1. Check whether records is existed by ey 2. If existed, run UPDATE query.

Comment: @YongShun hmm, just I don't need other columns for the business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Attach` and `Entry` methods to track the changes to a entity model. To identify the model you would need all the keys (here I'm considering only one primary key: `Id`)

```
var query = 
  from model in context
  where key == "someKey"
  select new myDTO
  {
    Id = model.Id,
    Item1 = model.column1,
    Item2 = model.column2
  };

var dto = query.First();

// Here I'm using Entity but you should use the right type
var entityyModified = new Entity();
entityModified.Id = dto.Id;
entityyModified.Item1 = dto.Item1;
entityyModified.Item2 = dto.Item2;

// ...
// Item1 or Item2 properties can be assigned to different values
// ...

// Save the changes
context.Attach(entityyModified);
var dbEntry = context.Entry(entityyModified);
dbEntry.Property(e => e.Item1).IsModified = true;
dbEntry.Property(e => e.Item2).IsModified = true;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thx, your solution works perfectly as I wish (although I should write some more lines of code)