# How to deep-copy instance's properties when updating an entity in the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, owned-types

Using Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET - I decided to encapsulate all the `Address` information into a class with the `[Owned]`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) attribute:

```
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Owned]
public class Address 
{
   public string? Street { get; set; }
   public string? City { get; set; }
   public string? Zipcode { get; set; }
   ...

   public void UpdateInfo(string? street, string? city, string? zipcode) 
   {
      this.Street = street;
      this.City = city;
      this.Zipcode = zipcode;
   }
}
```

And my entity have a property of type `Address`:

```
public class Person 
{
   ...
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Address Info { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

I'm encountering a problem when updating my entity's address information using my `UpdateInfo` method and [DbContext.Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-7.0).
When calling the method below, the updated data is not saved into the database:

```
public void UpdatePerson(int id)
{
    Person person = _dbContext.Persons.Find(id);
    person.Info.UpdateInfo("First Avenue", "New York City", "10001");

    _dbContext.Persons.Update(person);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

After some investigation I noticed that [DbContext.Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-7.0) makes a shallow copy of my `Person` instance, and if I instead do something like the code below, the data in the database will be updated correctly:

```
public void UpdatePerson_ForceDeepCopy(int id)
{
    Person person = _dbContext.Persons.Find(id);

    person.Info = new Address()
    {
        Street = "'First Avenue",
        City = "New York City", 
        Zipcode = "10001"
    };

    _dbContext.Persons.Update(person);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I don't like this solution so much, I would much rather updating the existing instance of `Address` over creating a new one.

Does anyone know if it's possible, and if so, how can I configure my `DbContext` to perform a deep copy of my `Owned` instances when I use [DbContext.Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-7.0)?

Thanks.

Comment: I think `_dbContext.Persons.Update(person);` is the wrong idea (unfortunately, sounds good, but it isn't). You probably want to `SaveChanges()`. See [how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657813/how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-core)

Comment: Use Include address something like this _dbContext.Persons.Include(x=>x.Info).Find(id) and save the same way you saving _dbContext.Persons.Update(person);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your first method to explicitly set the Info [property as modified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/entity-entries#working-with-a-single-property):

> SaveChanges will only update properties marked as modified. Set IsModified to true to force EF Core to update a given property value, or set it to false to prevent EF Core from updating the property value.

```
public void UpdatePerson(int id)
{

   Person person = _dbContext.Persons.Find(id);
   person.Info.UpdateInfo("First Avenue", "New York City", "10001");
   _dbContext.Entry(person).Property(s => s.Info).IsModified = true;
   _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

But anyway I would use the second method you showed, if we are really talking about the address of a person. [If the db context is set to track entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking), then this line is not needed:
`_dbContext.Persons.Update(person);`

if you really need not to instantiate an "Address" (maybe this is just an example) then my first suggestion should work.

Comment: It is not necessary to explicitly set IsModified before you call SaveChanges() - not normally. This is overkill.

Comment: I think the overkill is the requirement of not instantiating an "address". The second method should work even without the _dbContext.Persons.Update(person); assuming the dbcontext has tracking enabled

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure what you mean by *the requirement of not instantiating an "address"* ... or actually what is the second method you refer to either. So I guess I don't understand your last comment at all. My point mainly was that *normally" if you modify your entity then you call SaveChanges() and all is good (assuming it is tracked, of course). So no need to call Update() (as the OP did, wrongly I think) and no need to set IsModified() before you call SaveChanges().

Comment: the combination of owned properties (agreeable choice) + updating a "field" of the owned property (questionable) does not let the context be aware that there is something to update. The user explicitly says he does not want to instantiate an Info object (questionable, you can have reasons not to instantiate objects, but updating the address of a person isn't looking like a hot path were not instantiating objects make sense) so my answer just satisfies the expressed requirements.

Comment: though, I would use the second method in the question, removing the update as it is not needed. Instantiating an Address object and assignign it to the Info property would kick in the change tracker and the SaveChanges (which the user calls) would work.

Comment: *the combination of owned properties (agreeable choice) + updating a "field" of the owned property (questionable) does not let the context be aware that there is something to update* Is there any documentation for this. I would call this a bug if true - seems like if you change your entity in EFCore, it should understand it needs to be modified. My contention has been that the call to Update() was the problem in the OP's code that didn't work.